# Which song are they humming?

Tags: music, muv-luv

Is the song they are humming in episode 17 of muv luv alternative: Total Eclipse based on a real Russian song ? Or is it just some random song made up for the anime specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like they are humming the special ED (ep.17)/Insert Song (ep.24) "Snow Maiden" by Aki Misato:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TU7dq75L-s